# fid = stack.enter_context(open(os_fspath(file), "rb"))

Tags: pytorch

=> merge config from configs/swin_tiny_patch4_window7_224_lite.yaml
SwinTransformerSys expand initial----depths:[2, 2, 2, 2];depths_decoder:[1, 2, 2, 2];drop_path_rate:0.2;num_classes:9
---final upsample expand_first---
pretrained_path:./pretrained_ckpt/swin_tiny_patch4_window7_224.pth
---start load pretrained modle of swin encoder---
Namespace(accumulation_steps=None, amp_opt_level='O1', base_lr=0.01, batch_size=24, cache_mode='part', cfg='configs/swin_tiny_patch4_window7_224_lite.yaml', dataset='Synapse', deterministic=1, eval=False, img_size=224, list_dir='./lists/lists_Synapse', max_epochs=150, max_iterations=30000, n_gpu=1, num_classes=9, opts=None, output_dir='./output', resume=None, root_path='C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Swin-Unet-main\data\Synapse\train_npz', seed=1234, tag=None, throughput=False, use_checkpoint=False, zip=False)
The length of train set is: 1009
43 iterations per epoch. 6450 max iterations
0%|                                         | 0/150 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Swin-Unet-main/train.py", line 102, in 
trainer[dataset_name](args, net, args.output_dir)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Swin-Unet-main\trainer.py", line 57, in trainer_synapse
for i_batch, sampled_batch in enumerate(trainloader):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\PytorchCuda\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 435, in **next**
data = self._next_data()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\PytorchCuda\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 475, in _next_data
data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\PytorchCuda\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\PytorchCuda\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in 
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Swin-Unet-main\datasets\dataset_synapse.py", line 65, in **getitem**
data = np.load(data_path)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\PytorchCuda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 417, in load
fid = stack.enter_context(open(os_fspath(file), "rb"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Swin-Unet-main\data\Synapse\train_npz\case0001501_slice001.npz.npz'

Process finished with exit code 1

Please see if anyone knows the answer